garch model with fixed arma lags in R
I can't fit an ARMA-GARCH model with specific MA lags not estimated in time series data. For example I run the following code:
library(fGarch)
fitgi <- garchFit(~ arma(0,4)+ garch(1,1), data = gi, include.mean = F, trace = F)

and a part of the output is as below.

         Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
ma1     1.172e-01   2.991e-02    3.917 8.98e-05 ***
ma2     2.322e-02   2.917e-02    0.796   0.4260    
ma3    -1.301e-02   3.057e-02   -0.426   0.6703    
ma4    -6.619e-02   2.599e-02   -2.547   0.0109 *  
omega   2.570e-05   3.671e-06    7.000 2.55e-12 ***
alpha1  3.150e-01   3.728e-02    8.450  < 2e-16 ***
beta1   6.679e-01   2.393e-02   27.916  < 2e-16 ***

Since the ma2 and ma3 coefficients are not significant I would like to re-estimate the model estimating only the ma1 and ma4 coefficients for the arma model.
I tryed to fit an ARMA-GARCH model with fixed MA lags but I receive an error in the following code.
library(fGarch)
fitgi <- garchFit(~ arma(lag = list(ar=NULL, ma=c(1,4)))+ garch(1,1), 
  data = gi, include.mean = F, trace = F)

The error is :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In .garchInitSeries(formula.mean = formula.mean, formula.var = formula.var,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion

The arma model with fixed ma coefficients is working fine as a stadalone but when it is in a garchFit model it doesn't work. Is there a proposition how can I fit a garch model with some ARMA coefficients omitted from the estimation in R?
I would appreciate any suggestion.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

You can do that with rugarch:
library(rugarch)
set.seed(324)
gi=as.ts(rnorm(200, 0.01,0.3))
model <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 2), include.mean = TRUE),
  distribution.model = "norm",
  fixed.pars = list(ma2 = 0.86)  # Fix the ARMA lag parameter
)

fit <- ugarchfit(spec = model, data = gi)
fit@fit$robust.matcoef



          Estimate  Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.02883778  0.04945789   0.5830775 0.5598411386  
ar1     0.44670014  0.05100497   8.7579722 0.0000000000  
ma1    -0.85733472  0.01445475 -59.3116443 0.0000000000  
ma2     0.86000000          NA          NA           NA  
omega   0.03168054  0.01252427   2.5295328 0.0114214484  
alpha1  0.38166661  0.10492752   3.6374312 0.0002753707  
beta1   0.56281251  0.04875034  11.5447923 0.0000000000


Thank you for your help. Is it possible to ommit some ma coefficients? Because this is the problem. For instance to estimate only ma1 and ma4 coefficients and ommit ma2 and ma3?

Yu need to change  the code, for example: mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 4)  and fixed.pars = list(ma1 = 0,ma2=0,ma3=0) to estimate ma4. But think about why you need to do that, maybe is a problem with outliers in the ts.
